# Defining the free spectral range (FSR) in wavelength domain

Tags: optics

I've seen a lot of sources talk about a free spectral range in optical cavities (say, some planar Fabry-Perot type thing) with a plot of transmission vs. wavelength, but it doesn't make much sense to me because as I understand the spacing between transmission peaks isn't uniform with respect to wavelength.

Ignoring index of refraction for now (just say $n=1$), the transmission peaks occur at wavelengths $\lambda_m = L/m$, where $L$ is the optical length of the cavity and $m$ some integer. Since frequency and wavelength are inversely proportional, this means that the frequency peaks are uniformly spaced, and FSR makes sense when defined as the distance between frequency transmission peaks. But why is it even defined in terms of wavelength when it's only locally accurate?

Comment: This is a convenience thing mostly. The numbers for experimentally relevant things are easy to remember for wavelength. It is true that generally when talking about bandwidths of optical signals one has to be careful to say the central wavelength if using wavelength as a measure of bandwidth. For example 2 nm at 1550 nm is not the same bandwidth as 2 nm at 400 nm.